# Listview only the last date get deleted

Tags: android, listview, cardview

The following code consist of the listview function for displaying data from sqlite.

The issue is that no matter which data i selected on, it will only delete the last data and not the data being selected. How can i go about solving the issue? please help.

Thank you.

Arealist.java

```
public class Arealist extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static ListView listView;
    public static ArrayList<Area> list;
    AreaListAdapter adapter = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new AreaListAdapter(this, R.layout.area_items, list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);            

        //get all data
        Cursor cursor = MainActivity.sqLiteHelper.getData("SELECT * FROM AREA");
        list.clear();
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            int id = cursor.getInt(0);
            double area = cursor.getDouble(1);
            String date = cursor.getString(2);

            list.add(new Area(id, area, date));
        }

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems your problem is in this line **MainActivity.sqLiteHelper.deleteData(Area.getId());**

Try with this

```
MainActivity.sqLiteHelper.deleteData(area.getId());
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had tried on what you suggested however it give me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Make Area Object local.

set Area Id in delete buttons as a Tag and get it in onClick().

**Add In getView()**

```
 holder.btnDelete.setTag(area.getId());
```

**Add In OnClick()**

```
final int areaId = view.getTag();
```

**Add in AlertDialog:**

```
 MainActivity.sqLiteHelper.deleteData(areaId);
```